Why does the following regular expression ignore the [^=] part?
As tested on regex101.com for the regex: ^.+=[^=].+$ matches the following strings:
abc=fd

and
abc==qww

Even though I explicitly asked it not to match the second =.
As I understand it it should match: anything (.+) -> = -> NOT = -> anything (.+) yet it matches the second string as well.
Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

^.+ matches "abc=", = matches "=", [^=] matches "q", .+$ matches "ww". Don't use . "anything" if you don't mean it.

Ok, that really helps, thanks.

If, for the string "abc==qww", the regex engine stopped when ^.+= matched "abc=", [^=].+$ would be unable to match the remainder of the string, "=qww", so the attempted match would fail. That, however, would violate every regex engine's prime directive: "do whatever it takes to achieve a match when that is possible" (in this case by causing ^.+= to match "abc==").
